# How can I identify what JavaScript website is running?

Tags: javascript

Some websites have JavaScripts which are used for browser fingerprinting. I know these type of scripts check and send data back to server like: browser user agent, screen resolution, fonts list and etc. So my question would be: is it possible to inspect these scripts from client side? If yes, how?

Comment: i wrote this to bust <canvas> fingerprinting, one newer and particularly powerful method used by some: http://danml.com/notrack/  browse code:http://jsfiddle.net/976fuyyh/

Comment: Thanks. Canvas is not a problem, theres a handful of plugins to fight that type of fingerprinting. Apart from canvas there are many more things which builds bits of entropy. I'm looking to identify exact JS scripts website is running to fingerprint users/browsers/devices

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to inspect any script on any website with the right debugging tools and time to sort through things.

For any given web site, you can run a debugger like the Chrome debugger, open the network tab and see all network requests that the browser makes.  You would then have to sort through those requests to see which ones contained the information you are looking for.  If you then wanted to find the scripts responsible for those requests, you'd have to work backwards in analyzing the site and scripts to figure out which script contains the code making the request.

I am not aware of any automated way to detect exactly which requests contain the information you want.    Tools like [Disconnect.me](https://disconnect.me/) automatically shield your browser from some common tracking techniques of some common services, but that tool can also cause problems on some sites where the site won't then work properly.

Comment: What about something like `Object.defineProperty(window, "navigator", {get: function() { console.trace(); debugger; }})` to log all accesses?

Answer (score 1):

you can list all the scripts used by newer browsers thanks to performance.getEntries():

```
var scripts=[].slice.call(performance.getEntries())
 .map(function(a){return a.initiatorType==="script" && a.name; })
 .filter(Boolean);

alert(scripts); /* on this page in console: ["http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=aa4bf2e33f9d", "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=207a95000ab6", "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js?v=3a04bf1d3cc0", "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/post-validation.en.js?v=59400b6b717e", "http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/core.js?2", "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/external-editor.en.js?v=49dac339584c", "http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/api/is-participating?callback=wbParticipating2682405&accountId=2682405&host=stackoverflow.com&_=1418692483862", "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/wmd.en.js?v=988f5766f506"] */
```

if you know of any bad-behaving filenames, you can detect and counteract them, or feed the list of urls to something that can fetch and scan the script contents themselves; not sure what your end-goal is here...

Comment: Sorry for newbie question but where and how should I run the code provided by you? The end goal is to identify what type of JS website is using to identify users so I can create a work around for it.

Comment: @Born: this is the first step of that process; identifying what scripts the page is actually running (from JS).